# Flex UI get bad performance when change to normal screen from fullscreen mode

Tags: apache-flex, internet-explorer, actionscript, adobe, stage3d

I encountered an odd situation and it is only happens on IE.
Our project is a Flash 3D Game using Stage3D, and the Game GUIs are created by CS6.
When our game switch from the full screen( StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE or StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN ) to normal screen ( StageDisplayState.NORMAL ), the performance of the Game GUIs decline to about half FPS comparing to full screen mode.
But this condition is only happens on IE.

The Game is normal screen when it is initialized and the performance is as same as fullscreen. The performance degradation only happens after switch from fullscreen to normal screen.

Addition : When the mouse is out of the view, the performance become better, from 20 fps up to 50 fps. But is still not as same as the original 60 fps.

Addition 2 : My colleague told me the Flash Pro CS6 be used to built a single swc file per GUI, and then package all ui swc files to one swc file by Flex Framework SDK( the command is "compc" ). and the IE version = 9.0.8112.16421, the Flash Player Version = 11.6.602.155.

Addition 3 : I utilized Adobe Profiler Scout to observe the application, and I found that when it is normal screen after full screen, the time 「Waiting for GPU」 in 「Inactive」 grows up from 10ms to approximate 30ms which is triple. And in the 「Activity Sequence 」tab, it shows that the 「Waiting for GPU」 happens in the 「Copying to screen 」in 「DisplayObject List」.

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused; are you using the Flex Framework?  Or Flash Pro CS6?  It would be highly unusual to use the Flex Framework inside of CS6.  Also, you may specify which version of Flash Player/IE you are using.  There may be differences in the version of Flash Player built into IE10 due to the tight integration.

Comment: I had added some notes in the original text, please check it out, thanks.